# fs изменяет размер файла в два раза

Tags: node.js, fs

Когда я для теста решил прочитать exe файл с помощью fs и записать ничего не меняя, он резко вырос в размере в два раза.
[Скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY6gd.png)

Как это исправить?

```
async function crate() {
    var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("gd/GeometryDash.exe", 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  fs.writeFile("gd/GeometryDash1.exe", data, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
});
}
```

код ^

Comment: Может там не utf8?

Comment: Пытаться прочитать бинарные данные как текст - определённо плохая идея

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно читать бинарный файл не как текст в кодировке UTF8, а как буфер, и писать так же. По умолчанию файлы читаются как буферы, поэтому можно просто пропустить кодировку. Также, если на запись подаётся буфер, кодировка игнорируется, поэтому и там её можно пропустить:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function crate() {
  fs.readFile("gd/GeometryDash.exe", function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    fs.writeFile("gd/GeometryDash1.exe", data, function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: В скобках можно заметить, что это не самый лучший способ копировать файл. Даже если не рассматривать банальный метод fs.copyFile, лучше использовать стримы (fs.createReadableStream, fs.createWritableStream), а не вычитывать весь файл в память.